# Change Toast icon color conditional in React

Tags: react-native, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I would like to change the icon os the toast component using a condition. I am trying do it using a ternary operator, but is not working. 
Can anyone help me please?
I had the follow idea:

```
renderResultadoManifestacao(){
  var tag = '';
  const listItems = this.state.resultList.map((d) => 
  //<li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>);
    <Toast>
      {d.success == true ? tag = "success" : tag = "error" }
      <ToastHeader icon = {tag}> {d.chaveAcesso} </ToastHeader>
      <ToastBody>
        {d.resultado.map((r) =>
          <li key={r}>{r}</li>
        )}
      </ToastBody>
    </Toast>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {listItems }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe just remove the `const` keyword before the `tag` variable at the top because you're trying to replace its content in your condition

Comment: I am able to execute your code without any error.  What is your expectant? Following is codepen
https://codepen.io/munikumarofficial/pen/WNvMeGx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tag` variable inside the `map`'s function.

```
renderResultadoManifestacao(){
        const listItems = this.state.resultList.map((d) => {
            var tag = d.success ? "success" : "error";
            return <Toast>
                {tag}
                <ToastHeader icon = {tag}> {d.chaveAcesso} </ToastHeader>
                <ToastBody>
                    {d.resultado.map((r) =>
                        <li key={r}>{r}</li>
                    )}
                </ToastBody>
             </Toast>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {listItems}
            </div>
        );

}
```